# How to pass an object outside the function chrome.extension.sendRequest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to take the response from below and use outside the function.  The response is an object - specifically from localStorage and has 50 items.

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest(options, function(response){
console.log('answer back is ' + response.newone199);
console.log(response.newone);
var globalvar = response;

});

console.log(globalvar);
```

both console.logs provide the correct answer - but if move outside the function i get undefined.

I have tried return global var which does not work either - i read you cannot pass an object outside a function unless you put inside another function?  I tried that but was not able to make it work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591814/javascript-global-variable-not-working-properly) I ended up just wrapping my whole function like the following:

```
function doSomething(){
    chrome.extension.sendRequest(options, function(response){
        var thing = response.data;
        //Do something with our variable. 
        //The rest of the function goes here before the next bracket
    });
}
```

I know this isn't the most elegant solution but it worked for me.

Comment: i will give it a try - i just ended up doing everything in the sendRequest.

Answer (score 1):

in your code above, supose you declared *globalvar* outside the scope of the function:

```
1. var globalvar;
2. chrome.extension.sendRequest(options, function(response){
3.   console.log('answer back is ' + response.newone199);
4.   console.log(response.newone);
5.   globalvar = response;
6. });
7. console.log(globalvar);
```

then the execution order will be: 1,2,7,...,3,4,6,...
that's weil you get undefined